# udf spark column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, udf

I need to specify a sequence of columns. If I pass two strings, it works fine

```
val cols = array("predicted1", "predicted2")
```

but if I pass a sequence or an array, I get an error:

```
 val cols = array(Seq("predicted1", "predicted2"))
```

Could you please help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function signature is `def array(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column` which means that it takes one string and then one or more strings. If you want to use a sequence, do it like this:

```
array("predicted1", Seq("predicted2"):_*)
```

From what I can see [in the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L890), there are a couple of overloaded versions of this function, but neither one takes a `Seq` directly. So converting it into varargs as described should be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options here:

1. Using a `Seq[String]`:

   ```
   val columns: Seq[String] = Seq("predicted1", "predicted2")

   array(columns.head, columns.tail: _*)
   ```
2. Using a `Seq[ColumnName]`:

   ```
   val columns: Seq[ColumnName] = Seq($"predicted1", $"predicted2")

   array(columns: _*)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark's array form `def array(cols: Column*): Column` where the `cols` val is defined **without** using the `$` column name notation -- i.e. when you want to have a `Seq[ColumnName]` type specifically, but created using strings.  Here is how to solve that...

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val some_states: Seq[String] = Seq("state_AK","state_AL","state_AR","state_AZ")
val some_state_cols: Seq[ColumnName] = some_states.map(s => symbolToColumn(scala.Symbol(s)))

val some_array = array(some_state_cols: _*)
```

...using Spark's `symbolToColumn` method.

or with the `ColumnName(s)` constructor directly.

```
val some_array: Seq[ColumnName] = some_states.map(s => new ColumnName(s))
```